# How to launch DropBox using its python script normally?

Tags: python, dropbox

I've installed [Dropbox_2.2.10.tar.gz](http://linux.softpedia.com/progDownload/Dropbox-Download-41209.html).

Its [installation instruction](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) says: "Download [this Python script](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) to control Dropbox from the command line. For easy access, put a symlink to the script anywhere in your PATH"

Where should I put the script to run dropbox like other software which run from the terminal and the Dash?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really matter where you put that script, as long as you add the directory containing it to your PATH. You can do that by editing your `.profile` (type `gedit ~/.profile` in terminal) to add the line `PATH=/path/to/script:$PATH` (replace `path/to/script` with the correct path).

However, it might be a bad idea to simply add any directory to PATH, because whatever is in it will be added. You might want to create a folder named `bin` in your HOME and put the script there; I believe it's fairly standard, and it should already be in your PATH if it exists.